# Mathematica: How to plot several lines of a matrix in the same graph vertically

Tags: matrix, plot, wolfram-mathematica, line

I created an array named Theta with 100 lines and 400 columns. Each entry is a number. What I want to do is a graph that plots

0.01 vs every number in line 1

0.02 vs every number in line 2

...

1 vs every number in line 100

So basically every line is plotted vertically.

I can do this for each line, but I don't know how to do it for all of them at the same time. And doing all of 100 lines by hand is certainly not the way to go.

My code so far is:

```
data = Table[Theta[i][j], {i, 100}, {j, 400}];

Line1 = Table[data[[1, i]], {i, 1, 400}];

ListPlot[{MapIndexed[{0.01, #} &, Line1]]
```

EDIT:
Ok I've managed to finally do this.

If anyone is interested, here it goes:

```
data = Table[Theta][i][j], {i, 100}, {j, 400}];
final = {};
For[g = 1, g < 100, g++,
    Line[g] = MapIndexed[{0.01*g, #} &, Table[data[[g, i]], {i, 1, 400}]];
    final = Join[final, Line[g]];
]
ListPlot[final]
```

Comment: A little puzzled here, the second piece of code you posted seems to have some syntax issues. In particular, `Line` is a reserved symbol in Mathematica, so `Line[g]=...` will throw an error. The first piece of code creates a list, `data`, of the form `{{Theta[1][1], Theta[1][2], Theta[1][3],...},{Theta[2][1], Theta[2][2],...},...}`, which aren't numeric values. Are you happy that it is working as you intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example answer using a slightly smaller set of 10 lines of 40 columns of random numbers plotted at 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,...,1 instead of 0.01 intervals.

```
data = Table[x + RandomReal[5], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 40}];
```

Here is the data plotted:

```
ListPlot[ MapThread[ Function[x, {#2, x}] /@ #1 &, {data, Range[0.01, 1, .1]}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]